# URL of link from IFrame Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This question may seen before. But in my scenario I didn't get the success.
I have local HTML file loading in Iframe with sample external Link.

```
        <a href="http://www.boutell.com/">sample.com</a>
```

**Code:**

```
    <iframe id="iframe_Id" src="sample.html" 
style="background-color:white; height:100%; width:100%;" onload="Load()"; ></iframe>

    function Load() {
alert("loaded");
    var linkchange = document.getElementById("iframe_Id").contentWindow.location;
alert(linkchange);
}
```

While click on the external link I need the url value of particular anchor tag.

**Edit:** I know because of security policy we can't get URL when it is different domain.
But I need the value from my local HTML page(the Link URL What I Clicked ).
I didn't tried in this case

Any help is needed regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function in the parent window when you click on a link in the frame.

In the parent html you need to add a function to handle the call.  Something like

```
function iframeLinkClicked(url) {
     //do stuff
}
```

Then in the child window add a function to handle the click event of a hyperlink.

```
function linkClicked(hyperLink) {
    parent.iframeLinkClicked(hyperLink.href);
}
```

You need to add this to all hyperlinks

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="linkClicked(this);">google</a>
```

Now, when you click on a link, it will alert the parent window.

**Edit**: alternative to adding "onclick" to every hyperlink.

You can add the event to the frame elements when the frame is loaded, if the frame html is in the same domain.

This is the complete script in the parent page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function iframeLinkClicked(url) {
        alert(url);
    }
    function Load(iframe) {
        iframe.onload = null;
        try {
            var a = document.frames['iframe_Id'].document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i].onclick = function () {
                    parent.iframeLinkClicked(this.href);
                    return false;
                };
            }
        } catch (e) {

        }

    }
</script>
```

This will replace your current `Load()` function.  So the iframe still needs to have the load property set.

There is nothing to add to the child pages anymore.  It's all done here.

```
<iframe id="iframe_Id" src="sample.html" 
style="background-color:white; height:100%; width:100%;" onload="Load(this);" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Works good, But I struck in middle. Bcz I will load many HTML files into IFrame one by one
I have to add onclick to every anchor tag while loading into HTML page to IFrame & as well as function in the head tag.
It looks heavy in my case.
Can you suggest me any other suggestion if possible.
Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer so you don't have to make any changes to the child pages.  Just add the script to the parent page and it will set all the events there.

Comment: It works.. Now I know the **href** value.
One last question is I dont want to load that external link in my Iframe. I want to disable the onLoad event when click on link.

Comment: You set set onload to null in the load function so that it only calls `Load()` once.  You have to pass the iframe into the function by passing `this` as a parameter.  I updated my answer to show both the iframe markup and the updated function.  If this answer helped you, please mark it as the answer so others can find it.  Thank you.

Comment: yes.. Surely, I learned something; But still It didn't get my requirement.With out using onload the link URL is opening in IFrame.
Here I know one thing **If you set attribute `target` as `blank` it will open in new window.**

Comment: I want to use href URL in another browser when user click on link.
So what value I have to set to attribute target to do nothing. In  other words "when I click on link I don't want to open the link URL in IFrame or open in new browser & I need the URL of that link of href"..
I hope I am clear:)

Comment: I updated the answer.  In the click event, if you return `false`, it cancels the click and doesn't actually go anywhere.  That way you just get the URL value and no redirects or new windows occur.

Comment: I got what I want.. I greatly appreciate Your help :)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this:

```
var a = document.frames['iframe_Id'].document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) { 
  a[i].onclick = function() { 
    document.getElementById("iframe_Id").src = this.href;
    // and so on whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

Comment: var a =document.frames['iframe_Id'].document.getElementsByTagName('a');
This one works...